# Multiple buffer subtraction?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, clip

I've created two different buffers (1 mile and 3 miles) in ArcMap, I need to see how many people live within 1 and 3 miles. In other words, I need to subtract the bigger buffer from the smaller one. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: clip http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Clip_%28Analysis%29

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, then you should use Erase from Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

To do this try using the [Erase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm) tool which:

> Creates a feature class by overlaying the Input Features with the
>   polygons of the Erase Features. Only those portions of the input
>   features falling outside the erase features outside boundaries are
>   copied to the output feature class.